# Unable to understand casting in C

Tags: c, casting

I have a library function whose signature is as follows:

```
sgx_status_t sgx_unseal_data(
const sgx_sealed_data_t * p_sealed_data,
uint8_t * p_additional_MACtext,
uint32_t * p_additional_MACtext_length,
uint8_t * p_decrypted_text,
uint32_t * p_decrypted_text_length
);
```

Now, for the  uint32_t * p_decrypted_text_length.

Case 1: Pass

```
  char resecret[50];
  uint32_t resecret_len = sizeof(resecret);

  status = sgx_unseal_data(
          (sgx_sealed_data_t*)sealed_data,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          (uint8_t*)&resecret,
          (uint32_t*)&resecret_len); //Notice last parameter
```

Case 2: Fails

```
  char resecret[50];
//  uint32_t resecret_len = sizeof(resecret);
  status = sgx_unseal_data(
          (sgx_sealed_data_t*)sealed_data,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          (uint8_t*)&resecret,
          (uint32_t*)&(sizeof(resecret))); //Notice last parameter
```

My question is why the second case fails. What am I missing in casting? Also, if you could explain a little more about casting between uint_8t, uint_32t, size_t and their pointer cousins.

Comment: `&(sizeof(resecret))` ??

Comment: [C11 - §6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators (p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2) The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, **the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.**

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Think `&((uint32_t){sizeof resecret})` would work?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still working that over in my hamster brain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's probably happening is that the `sgx_unseal_data` function emulates *pass by reference* here.

You pass a pointer to a variable, so the function can dereference the pointer to do assignment.

The value returned by `sizeof` is a compile-time value, a so called [*rvalue*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Non-lvalue_object_expressions). First of all you can't get the address of those values, it's like trying to get the address of an integer literal (like e.g. `&12` which is nonsense). Secondly, even if it was valid to get the address of an rvalue, the assignment to that location would be worthless since you have no variable where it would be stored.

The problem have nothing to do with the casting at all, just that you can't get the address of an rvalue.

Comment: Detail: C calls `12` an _integer constant_.  All literals in C, there are only 2: _string literal_ and _compound literal_, can have their address taken.

Comment: With taking address of _literals_, the adders and the _literal_ itself are valid until the end of the block.

Comment: @coderredoc That's true about `sizeof` and VLAs, it's still an rvalue but calculated at runtime.